# How to get unique count in Python?

Tags: python, django, count

I am making a simple app where you downvote and upvote different posts. I am buildig it in Python/Django...i get the upvote/downvote count by storing a user id and a comment id into the Upvote model and through the association there is a count of 1. It's printing out the right number in the view except for its printing out the count the number of times that is is upvoted. For example, if its 1 it will print : 1, but if its 3 it will print : 3 3 3. How do i change my logic so that it only prints out the number once?

View page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Topic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
    <hr>
        <a href="/users/{{topic.user.id}}/">{{topic.user.first_name}} </a>posted a topic:
        <hr>
        Topic: {{topic.topic}}
        <br>
        Description: {{topic.description}}
        <hr>
        <h3>Post your answer</h3>
        <form action="/topic/{{topic.id}}/post" method="post">
            {%csrf_token%}
            <textarea name="comment" id="" cols="20" rows="2" required style="resize:none"></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Post">
        </form>
        <hr>
        {% for comment in comments %}
            <a href="/users/{{comment.user_id}}/">{{comment.user.first_name}}</a>: {{comment.comment}}
            <br>
                <a href="/delete/{{comment.id}}/">Delete Post</a>
                <h5>Number of upvotes:</h5>
            {% for upvote in upvotes %}
                {% if upvote.comment_id == comment.id %}
                        {{upvotes.count}}
                {%endif%}
            {%endfor%}
                <h5>Number of downvotes: </h5>
            {% for downvote in downvotes %}
                {% if downvote.comment_id == comment.id %}
                    {{downvotes.count}}
                {%endif%}
            {%endfor%}  
            <hr>
            <a href="/upvote/{{comment.id}}/"><button>Upvote</button></a>
            <a href="/downvote/{{comment.id}}/"><button>Downvote</button></a>
            <br>
            <form action="/idea/{{comment.id}}/" method="post">
            {%csrf_token%}
            <textarea name="idea" id="" cols="20" rows="2" required style="resize:none"></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Comment">
            </form>
                {% for idea in ideas %}
                    {% if idea.comment_id == comment.id %}
                        <a href="/users/{{idea.user_id}}/">{{idea.user}}</a> 
                        says: {{idea.idea}}
                        <a href="/delete/{{idea.id}}/comment">Delete Comment</a>
                    {%endif%}
                {%endfor%}
        {%endfor%}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your code

```
    {% for upvote in upvotes %}
            {% if upvote.comment_id == comment.id %}
                    {{upvotes.count}}
            {%endif%}
    {%endfor%}
```

you end up printing `upvotes.count` for `upvotes` times. You can completely get rid of the whole for loop and just use `{{upvotes.count}}`.

Comment: but there are multiple upvote counts for different comments. so in the views.py when i grab upvotes I grab upvotes = Upvote.objects.all() and then in my template i check if the upvote.comment_id == comment.id and if it is then i print it out. So that wouldnt work?

Comment: Maybe you should do the counting in the application logic and not within the view. Take a different variable,  increment it when `upvote.comment_id == comment.id` and then pass it to your view. Otherwise you need to increment a different variable within your view and then print it when your loop is done.

Comment: I second the idea above, I would just count the number of Upvote.objects.all() and pass a variable with the view that is that count.

Comment: Dang..is there really not another way to do it in the view..i'm trying to create a counter in the function that increments but thats not seeming to work:

Answer (score 0):

This is my function now...trying to increment a variable in the function called counter..i have it in the model as an integer field with a default=0

```
def upvote(request, comment_id):
    print "upvoting comment"
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id'])
    comment = Comment.objects.get(id=comment_id)
    upvote = Upvote()
    counter = 1
    upvote.comment = comment
    upvote.user = user
    upvote.created_at = timezone.now()
    upvote.counter = upvote.counter + 1
    upvote.save()
    print upvote.counter
    return redirect('/dashboard')
```

and the model...

```
class Upvote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="upvote_user", null=True)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, related_name="comment_upvote", null=True)
    counter = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False, default=0)
    created_at = models.DateField(null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'upvote'
```

views.py render function for template..

```
def show_topic(request, topic_id):
    print "Showing a topic"
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    comments = Comment.objects.all().filter(topic=topic)
    upvotes = Upvote.objects.all()
    ideas = Idea.objects.all()
    downvotes = Downvote.objects.all()
    context = {'upvotes': upvotes, 'ideas': ideas, 'comments': comments, 'topic': topic,'downvotes': downvotes}
    return render(request, 'discussionboard/show.html', context)
```

Comment: can u show us your render function for the template?

Comment: hey ferdy, just added it.